# Identify unique set of cells for each row in a matrix

Tags: compression, information-theory

I have a matrix with dimensions 500 x 10000. Each row represents a sample. I want to find for each sample a set of cells that only identify that sample. Thus I am looking for a reduced matrix 500 x n. Where n <10000. Is there any algorithm already developed that would help me?

Comment: What's the range and precision of the cell values, or, how many different values are possible?

Comment: The range is a set of 5 integers (from 0 to 4)

Answer (score 0):

This example in R doesn't necessarily yield an optimal solution (which in wise foresight you didn't request), but is quite quick:

```
# generate sample matrix
m = matrix(sample(0:4, 500*10000, T), 500, 10000)
# find smallest i for which the first i columns are unique over all sample rows
for (i in 4:10000) if (nrow(unique(m[, 1:i])) == 500) break
```